# MariaDB can't accept speacial font when it's insert/update throw query?

Tags: php, utf-8, mariadb

DB : MariaDB 10.0.32
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 8
Language : PHP 5.6.33

table A sets charset : utf8mb4, collation utf8mb4_general_ci.

I want to insert "  .mp3" to table A. << as you can see Me In is speacial font I guess.
Insert worked and data shown ?????? ?????.mp3 like this.

I tried to insert using inov() function utf8 to ascii code and it worked but I still need to use utf8 because of other contries language not ascii.

Is it posibble to insert " .mp3" to MariaDB instead of ??? ???.mpe like this?

done :

1. using inov() function utf8 to ascii. and it worked like "Me In.mp3".
2. tried to use sqlite.<< it works but I must use MariaDB. can not change DBMS.
3. table and DB set utf8mb4, utf8mb4_general_ci.

expecting :

1. insert MariaDB without broken characters to .
2. can use all langauges (includes English)

Comment: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/283366)

Comment: PHP 5.6? Upgrade! Anyhow, no, the DB only stores text (Unicode). Of course, that text can contain any text-based markup language. That said, you write something to the DB but what you retrieve differs, which would be a bug. If you want help, extract and provide a [mcve], so that everyone here can reproduce this.

Comment: That isn't how text works in computers. Font, size, colour, shadow, animation... are attributes generated by programs when displaying text. Use [Unicode Inspector](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%F0%9D%99%88%F0%9D%99%9A+%F0%9D%99%84%F0%9D%99%A3) and you'll see you have mathematical symbols.